# Applying Filters in Perl using Regex

Tags: regex, perl

I'm trying to extract text and numbers from a string using regex in perl. Here is my code:

```
$line = "finish=100\n";
($var) = $line =~ /[a-z]+/;
($val) = $line =~ /[0-9]+/;
```

My expected output is that $var = "finish" and $val = 100. However when I run the code $var = 1 and $val = 1.

Any help would be appreciated!!

Answer (score 4):

Use capturing parentheses inside your regular expressions:

```
$line = "finish=100\n";
($var) = $line =~ /([a-z]+)/;
($val) = $line =~ /([0-9]+)/;
print "$var $val\n";
```

Refer to [perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html)

Answer (score 3):

A regex match in list context (where the regex doesn't use the `/g` flag) returns

- the empty list if it fails
- a list of captured substrings (`$1, $2, ...`) if it succeeds and the pattern contains capturing groups
- the list `1` if it succeeds and the pattern doesn't capture anything

Your regexes match, but they don't contain any capturing groups, so that's why you get `1` in `$var` and `$val`.

If you add capturing groups (`/([a-z]+)/`, `/([0-9]+)/`), you get the matched substrings instead.

Note that it might be easier to just do it all in one match:

```
my ($var, $val) = $line =~ /^([a-z]+)=([0-9]+)$/;
```

This way you also validate that the input string has the expected form and isn't just something like `"Cat o' 9 tails"`, which (with your original regexes) would extract `$var = "at"` and `$val = "9"`.

Answer (score 0):

You can too get two values in one array, maybe with this:

```
$line = "finish=100\n";
@matches = $line =~ /(\w+)\W(\d+)/;
print "$matches[0], $matches[1]";
```